# Using DFSORT, writing multiple rows into one, based on a criteria

Tags: mainframe, dfsort

I have a daily report dataset, where details of several markets exist; one row per market. The record format looks like

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+--- 
MARKET NAME1     valm1       valm2
MARKET NAME2     valm1       valm2
MARKET NAME3     valm1       valm2
MARKET NAME4     valm1       valm2
```

Now, i need to pull all the above rows on to a single row of a monthly report file, record format could be:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---
DATE    MARKET NAME1     MARKET NAME2     MARKET NAME3     MARKET NAME4     
DATE1   valm1   valm2    valm1   valm2    valm1   valm2    valm1   valm2
```

How can we achieve it? Have an option for now to do it is via a job using DFSORT.
Appreciate your interest.

Answer (score 1):

ICEtool has an option Splice which could be used to merger multiple lines in to a single line .Please refer some icetool manual for exact syntax.